# What would be an efficient algorithm to sort millions of lines of integers in a file?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, complexity-theory

Count sort may not work in this case as as the value range of k is Big.

Can quick sort be Used for big data?

Comment: Use `Arrays.sort` or `Collections.sort` in the `java.util` package.

Comment: If we’re sorting fixed-size integers, [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) very efficient !

Comment: typically, millions is not big data. billions maybe.

Comment: No adding them to a collection would be a big over head.I have to write it back to the file as well.

Comment: Well this is for a prototype. Actual data would run into billions.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot `value range of k is Big`

Comment: @TheNewIdiot The integers don't even need to be fixed-size. Zero is a perfectly valid position value in radix sort. Plus, since it's not a comparison sort you never have to have more than one value in memory. Just read a value, look at it and determine which of 10 (assuming decimal) intermediate output files to put it in.

Answer (score 0):

Millions of elements is typically not considered big data, so I believe in this case quick-sort will do the trick.

You can fasten it somewhat by splitting the array into `q` subarrays, sorting them in parallel, and then use **k-way-merge** to merge the resulting sorted subarrays.

---

However, **if your data is really huge** (10^9+) - you want to consider distributing the job to a cluster of machines.

One scalable approach to do it is **[map-reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)**.

[The first slides of this class](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse490h/08au/lectures/algorithms.pdf) discusses sorting with Map-Reduce.

You might want to try the java open-source implementation, called [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/).

Comment: If i have to choose between Map-Reduce/Hadoop/UNIX sort , which would be faster ? Also i have to save it back to a file , how would that implementation work(im new to this) ?

Comment: @David Map-Reduce and Hadoop are basically the same thing (Hadoop is an implementation of MapReduce). Unix sort is perfectly fine if your data is only on the scales of millions. If I remember correctly - it is implemented as an external sort, which is efficient for large files, and does not require a lot of programming work from you. However, if your data is really huge (dozens of GBs at least), a more scalable approach (such as the MR solution) should be considered.

Comment: if i have sets( say around 10) of 50 million entries each, all sorted individually, how efficient would it be to use merger sort on them(not the splitting part).... just merging them. ?

Comment: For 10^9+ elements, you can use k-way-merge (with k intermediate files containing sorted data) where n/k is the amount of data that can fit into memory. @David If `k` is the number of sets, I believe it would take `O(n log k)` if you use a heap. This would be dominated by the `O(n log n)` for a reasonably small `k` such as 10.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is too large to fit into main memory, the first thing I would try is the [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/), a STL replacement for external memory algorithms. It should be much easier to use than setting up a Hadoop cluster. It also does multi-core parallelism.

That's C++ though, you might want to google for a Java equivalent if Java is a hard requirement.